# How could I create an infinite scroll down grid loader in a scrollable section with Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter framework and bootstrap, into this installation I have some sub-pages, in one of them I'm trying to have an infinite scroll loader.
For this purpose I'm using a jQuery downloaded from this tutorial [gridScrollFx.js](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/05/15/recreating-the-design-samsung-grid-loading-effect/comment-page-2/#comment-464575).
This is my JS file:

```
;( function( window ) {

'use strict';

var docElem = window.document.documentElement,
    support = { animations : Modernizr.cssanimations },
    animEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
        'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
        'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
        'animation' : 'animationend'
    },
    // animation end event name
    animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ];
...
...
// add to global namespace
window.GridScrollFx = GridScrollFx;
} )( window );
```

I get from console this error: "undefined is not a function" for this row:

```
animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' )
```

The page where I'm trying to have this effect looks like this:

```
<head>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/themes/<?php echo $this->config->item("theme"); ?>/normalize.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/themes/<?php echo $this->config->item("theme"); ?>/component.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>  
</head>  

<div class="container">
        <section class="grid-wrap">       
            <ul class="grid swipe-right" id="grid">

            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/themes/<?php echo $this->config->item("theme"); ?>/images/dummy.png" alt="dummy"><h3>A fantastic title</h3></a></li>
...
...


            </ul>
        </section>   

    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/colorfinder-1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/gridScrollFx.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/classie.js"></script>

        <script>
            new GridScrollFx( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), {
                viewportFactor : 0.4
            } );
        </script>
</div>
```

How could I solve this Javascript problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from PHP, so maybe reading this wrong. But I`ll try:

> function( window )

you have no function name, only a parameter. Window is the parameter of the function. Try out finding what the name should be by followint the tutorial?

Comment: it's because the Js file end with:  `// add to global namespace
 window.GridScrollFx = GridScrollFx;

} )( window );`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because your `modernizr.custom.js` doesn't include optional `Modernizr.prefixed()` module.

You'll need to download the [modernizr library](http://modernizr.com/download/) and select `Modernizr.prefixed()` module under "Extensibility" section.